# arduino error in IDE while uploading the code to arduino uno

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

--->this is the error I got

avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

```
     System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf"

     Using Port                    : COM4
     Using Programmer              : arduino
     Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
```

avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\.\COM4": The system cannot find the file specified.

avrdude done.  Thank you.

--->Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1

--->the two lights are on arduino, in IDE it's showing that "arduino Uno on COM4", same error.
--->if i go to device manager,under ports there is exclamatory mark. [arduino connected[device manager under ports showing exclamatory in triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaY78.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoMQE.jpg)

i've tried many onlilne solutions for 2 days, i'm getting same error..

Comment: Try reinstalling the Arduino IDE, so the drivers get reinstalled. Additionally it's always a good idea to have a second USB cable and Arduino Board, so you can test if the error persist when using another board/cable

Comment: @Elerium115 I've done that already, same error

Comment: could you post a screenshot?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoMQE.jpg

Comment: A screenshot of the error of course

Answer (score 1):

on the arduino-forum one guy had the same error:

https://forum.arduino.cc/t/cant-open-device-com4/912811/8

"*...I think I found out how to fix my problem! In Device manager I clicked on show hidden devices and then I could see that there was a hidden uno was using COM4. I uninstalled it and then changed the correct uno to COM4. That still didn't work until I disconnected the uno and plugged it back in. Then the upload worked....*"

Maybe this is also a solution for you.

Comment: but it didn't worked for me